# Download entire website with first degree sub-urls

Tags: windows, gratis, download-manager

I would like to download a website and all of its first degree sub-urls, as txt or html files. For example, I would like to download:

google.com
and google.com/10001
and google.com/10002
etc.
but not google.com/1001/1002

HTTrack is not slow at downloading, but before downloading, it scans all urls which is very very slow.

Software must run on Windows and be gratis.

I need to bypass robot.txt

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't HTTrack allow to set the recursion level? [See this](https://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html):

> httrack THE_SITE_URL -O /tmp/shoesizes -r50
>
> In this example, we limit the directlry depth to 50 levels deep.  As
>   a general rule, web sites don't go much deeper than 20 levels or so,
>   and if you think about it, if there are only 2 subdirectories per
>   directory level, a directory structure 50 deep would have about 10
>   trillion directories.  Of course many sites have a small number of
>   files many levels deep in a directory structure for various reasons. 
>   In some cases, a symbolic link will cause an infinite recursion of
>   directory levels as well, so placing a limit may be advisable.

-----Otherwise---
**VisualWget** should help you do this. Setting the depth/level of the recursion should help you.

[VisualWget third-party manual](https://earthsci.stanford.edu/computing/hosting/usingvisualwget.php)

However, the link to VisualWget is broken in that manual. Google a bit and you should find the actual one. I will update this a little later. (I did use it a yesterday at home.)